# How to load default HTML file in sublime text 3?

Tags: sublimetext3

Am using Sublime Text 3 and have seen some people loading default HTML content / template just by typing words like `html5`or `doctype`. Which package do i need to use for getting same control ?

Answer (score 15):

The `html` snippit is included in Sublime Text 3 by default.

From an empty file, set the syntax to HTML (either by saving the empty file with a `.html` extension, or by pressing `Ctrl+Shift+P` to open the command bar, and searching for "Set Syntax: HTML").

Then type `html` into the file, and press tab. Sublime Text should expand the snippet, giving you a basic HTML file with doctype, head, and body tags.

Comment: This does not work for me.  I can type html and hit tab to get boilerplate html, but it is missing <!DOCTYPE html> at very top.  Yes I have made sure the file type is html, and it is saved.  I'm using version 2.0.2.

Comment: @Alyoshak
I have updated the answer, it should work now you have to type : !html and then press tab.

Comment: @rahim.nagori Just tested with v3.2.2 and it works as per my instructions.

Answer (score 0):

Try emmet plugin. It provides this sort of functionality.  https://emmet.io/